# Control signals for a R-type instruction

Tags: signals, controls, mips, processor

I want to find what control signals are used and what their values are for an R-type instruction for a multi-cycle processor, particularly in the fetch stage.

I deduced the following. In the **F-stage, we have to fetch the instruction and increment the program counter.**

**To fetch the instruction, we have to access memory.** However, **the control signal table for R-type instructions show 0 for memRead and memWrite.** Hence, I'm not sure what control signal should be asserted to fetch instruction.

In *Pattterson and Henessey's* textbook on Computer Organization, it notes that "controls signals to read *instruction memory*" should be asserted.

My questions are the following:

1. Currently, I have asserted PCsource and PCwritecond. I'm not sure which signals *must* be deasserted.
2. Is instruction memory different from data memory?
3. Which control signals should be active to fetch instruction from memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In multi cycle processor the instruction memory and data memory are combined and of course that control signals for `memWrite` and `memRead` are 0 and `IRWrite` is asserted during fetch step.

According to *Harris & Harris* the first step for any instruction is to fetch the instruction from memory at the address held in the *PC*.

The **FSM** enters this state on reset.
To read memory, `IorD = 0`, so the address is taken from the PC. `IRWrite`is asserted
to write the instruction into the instruction register, *IR*. Meanwhile, the PC
should be incremented by `4` to point to the next instruction. Because the
ALU is not being used for anything else, the processor can use it to compute
`PC + 4` at the same time that it fetches the instruction.
`ALUSrcA = 0`, so
`SrcA` comes from the *PC*. `ALUSrcB = 01`, so `SrcB` is the constant 4.
`ALUOp = 00`, so the **ALU** decoder produces `ALUControl = 010` to make
the **ALU** add. To update the PC with this new value, `PCSrc = 0`, and
`PCWrite` is asserted.

**Control signals during Fetch step.**

> IorD = 0
>
> AluSrcA = 0
>
> ALUSrcB = 01
>
> ALUOp = 00
>
> PCSrc = 0
>
> IRWrite = aseerted
>
> PCWrite = asserted